# How to run an ftp batch file from QTP?

Tags: qtp

I have an ftp batch file as follows:

```
open <server>
<user>
<Password>
bin
cd \Curr_QA_DataLoad
put C:\Users\niprakash\Documents\XYZ\7090\NitishaQTPTest.txt
bye
```

I have to run this batch file from QTP. Manually I type ftp.exe -s: to run it. But this isnt working with QTP. Also I want the output of this sent to another file. Please help

Comment: What happens when "this isn't working with QTP"? And are you using WScript shell, Systemutil or InvokeApplication?

Answer (score 2):

```
SystemUtil.Run  "c:\abc\def\doFTP.bat"
```

or if you have parameters to send to your bat file , then

```
SystemUtil.Run  "c:\abc\def\doFTP.bat" ,  file1 &"   "& file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this, which just now figured out during a POC

'This is for SUB, creating a text file with FTP commands

```
Sub OpenTextFileTest
   Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\works\MISC\testfile.txt", ForWriting, True)
   f.Writeline "open your ftp ip"
   f.Writeline "tabc" 'Username
   f.Writeline "xyz" ' Password
   f.Writeline "lcd C:\Works\MISC\test" 'local working directory on your computer, test.txt to be sent to the ftp server
   f.WriteLine "cd ftp_folder"  ' your folder on the ftp location
   f.Writeline "send test.txt"
   f.writeline "disconnect"
   f.WriteLine "Close"
End Sub
OpenTextFileTest             'Calling the sub

Set app=CreateObject("Wscript.shell") '' Simple code to send keys to the command propmt, pretty simple
SystemUtil.run("cmd.exe")
app.sendkeys "cd C:\works\MISC"
app.sendkeys "~" 'its for enter key
app.SendKeys "ftp -s:testfile.txt"
app.SendKeys "~"
app.SendKeys "quit"
app.SendKeys "~"
app.SendKeys "exit"
app.SendKeys "~"
```

I have tested this code and it works awesome, post again if you any issues.